# How to change Table name in Realm Android?

Tags: android, realm

There is `User` table in APP version 1.0: 
    
    `@Table(name="User1")
    public class User extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        public int    uid;
        @Required
        public String name;
    }`

In APP version 2.0, add a field `age`:
    
    `@Table(name="User2")
    public class User extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        public int    uid;
        @Required
        public String name;
        public int    age;
    }`

I usually **change** `User` **table name** in version 2.0 by changing **annotation**, because it's easier then call `ADD COLUM age`.

How should i do in **realm API**?
i've try `@DefineTable` but does not work.

Comment: I think realm migration will work  see this link https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java#L78-L78

Answer (score 2):

```
@RealmClass(name = "reviewWords")
```

open class ReviewWords : RealmObject() {}

Answer (score 0):

The 'table' name of the model in Realm's underlying storage engine is decided by the class name. Realm doesn't have either `@Table` or `@DefineTable` annotation to name the 'table' right now.

If you want to change it, you can just rename the class and implement the proper migration. See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations.

Comment: i don't want to call `addField` or `removeField`. If the requirement changes every version，i have to write code in `Migration` every time i change `User`. i think it's stupie.